# create-react-app not working ?? Any Help is Appreciated

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

just tried creating my first react app but surely react is not in a mood to welcome me.
Just after installing everything node and create-react-app even checking their versions to make sure they are installed.I moved on to creating the react app using npm create-react-app my-app command but it has given me this error and i am not able to resolve.
Any HELP will be appreciated.
[image: Error running command]

I even tried updating the config file but Showed these errors as well.
[image: Error running npm config]

Comment: Please try `npx create-react-app my-app` or `npm init react-app my-app`

Comment: Did you read the create-react-app [getting started](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) guide? They recommend ***not*** installing `create-react-app` and running it via `npx`, i.e. `npx create-react-app my-app`. Also ensure you have the correct versions of node (8.10+) and npm (5.2+) installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the create-react-app github repository wiki. Please go through the detailed step by step instructions.

npx

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

(npx is a package runner tool that comes with npm 5.2+ and higher)

npm

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

npm init  is available in npm 6+

Yarn

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Reference Link: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app